# Run Jquery/JS function on button click with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 5 buttons all of them need to run the same function on click or onSubmit idk what the best way to do this is..But i need to pass the buttons ID as a parameter to the function. The buttons are running the function BuyItem(button id), I need the button to be past so i can run the same function and just distinguish which they are buying based off the button id being passed.

The buttons are being created in my php file

```
<input type='button' id='$id' name='$id' onSubmit="funciton($id)" style='width:185px;'value='Buy Tool'>
```

I dont know if thats how i should call the function but when the button is click i need to have the id passed to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.id` will give the current id of the element

```
<input type='button' id='$id' name='$id' onSubmit="Funciton(this.id)" style='width:185px;'value='Buy Tool'>
```

then your js would be

```
Funciton(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that:

```
<input 
    type='button' 
    id='777' 
    onclick="javascript:alert('I am button'+this.attributes.id.value)" 
    value='Buy Tool'>
```